# Phonegap app with remote database

Tags: php, json, ajax, jquery-mobile, phonegap

PT/EN
How do I create an phonegap app and conect to a remote database in an web server just to read some data, like a location of a classroom in a college, showing to user the floor and the building to go? I already have the cordova project, just need to know the conections via ajax, json, php, jquery mobile and some thing that I read in the web

Answer (score 0):

I do it this way combination with PHP. I also include the Jquery mobile library. So u can do more research on jquery mobile if you interested.

```
 <script>
 $(document).on("pageshow", "#ClassRoomPage", function()
{    
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: link + "[Your remote address]/[your remote address php script].php",
    data: {argument:value, argument:value, argument:value
    } ,
    datatype : "json",
    success: function(value) {
        var value = JSON.parse(value);
        $("#classList").html(value.t);
    },
    error: function(err) { 
        console.debug("error: "+err);
    }
});
   });
   </script>
   <div data-role="page" id="ClassRoomPage" data-url="index.html"></div>
```

On remote server site with php script as similar to below

```
    include("dbconfig.php");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin");   
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    if(isset($_POST['class']))
    {
       $class_id = $_POST['class'];
       $sql = "select * from classroom where class_id = '$class_id'";
       $rs = mysql_query($sql);
       $i=0;
       while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
       {
       $array_list[$i]['class_code'] = $rows['class_code'];
       $array_list[$i]['class_loc'] = $rows['class_loc'];
       ...
       }
       echo json_encode($array_list);
    }
    ?>
```